# Scheduled Cron Expressions does not work as expected

Tags: spring, cron

I'm tring to run a function every 10 minutes.

According to the documentation, it is stated that e.g `("0 0/5 * * *?"`) Runs every 5 minutes since the program started, but why when I change 5 by 10 `("0 0/10 * * *?"`), the function does not run every 10 minutes e.g (10:10 - 10:20 - 10:30)

Is it really me who misunderstands the Cron Expressions or the syntax is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is typo in :

```
"0 0/10 * * *?"
```

should be

```
"0 0/10 * * * ?"
```

here is the useful resource [CronMaker is a utility which helps you to build cron expressions. CronMaker uses Quartz open source scheduler.](http://www.cronmaker.com/)